# Oracle SQL: using LAG function with user-defined-type returns "inconsistent datatypes"

Tags: sql, oracle, function, user-defined-types

I have a type MyType defined as follows:

```
create or replace type MyType as varray(20000) of number(18);
```

And a table MyTable defined as follows:

```
create table MyTable (
   id       number(18) primary key
  ,widgets  MyType
)
```

I am trying to select the widgets for each row and its logically previous row in MyTable using the following SQL:

```
select  t.id
       ,lag(t.widgets,1) over (order by t.id) as widgets_previous
from MyTable t
order by t.id;
```

and I get the response:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got MYSCHEMA.MYTYPE
```

If I run the exact same query using a column of type varchar or number instead of MyType it works fine.

The type of the column in the current row and its previous row must be the same so I can only assume it is something related to the user defined type.

Do I need to do something special to use LAG with a user defined type, or does LAG not support user defined types? If the latter, are there any other utility functions that would provide the same functionality or do I need to do a traditional self join in order to achieve the same?

Comment: I can't test this myself right now, unfortunately, but what happens if you do: `lag(t.widgets, 1, cast(null as mytype)) over (order by t.id)`?

Comment: @Boneist - I'm afraid I still get the ORA-00932 -thanks though, a great idea!

Comment: An alternative to using the nested table would be to explicitly create a table and store your data in that, and then have a fkey from the new table back to the mytable (and then use SQL to compare datasets). Otherwise, a self join is probably the easiest way of doing this (ie. find the previous row's id and join that to the current id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading all the above I've opted for the following as the most effective method for achieving what I need:

```
select curr.id
      ,curr.widgets  as widgets
      ,prev.widgets  as previous_widgets
from (select  a.id                                      
             ,a.widgets
             ,lag(a.id,1) over (order by a.id)  as previous_id
      from mytable a
     ) curr
     left join mytable prev on (prev.id = curr.previous_id)
order by curr.id
```

ie. a lag / self join hybrid using lag on a number field that it doesn't complain about to identify the join condition. It's fairly tidy I think and I get my collections as desired. Thanks to everyone for the extremely useful input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` with UDT. The problem is `varray`

Does this give you a result?

```
select  t.id
       ,lag(
              (select listagg(column_value, ',') within group (order by column_value) 
                  from table(t.widgets))
            ,1) over (order by t.id) as widgets_previous
from MyTable t
order by t.id;
```

Comment: Hi @Kacper sadly my problem is a combined one: Part 1: I am unable to use nested tables over varrays (even though I would really like to) because as at 12c Oracle appears not to support nested tables as columns in temporary tables (ORA-14457).  Part 2: I'm familiar with listagg and for a different use-case it may work however I'm after collections so I can use Oracle "multiset" operators to perform various comparisons. - thank you so much for your input!

Comment: `select t.id, t2.widgets from MyTable t left outer join MyTable t2 on (t.id = t2.id + 1);` won't this solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @Kacper this approach is conceptually similar to what I've gone for below however it relies on consecutive id values which cannot be guaranteed in my scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
SQL> create or replace type TestType as varray(20000) of number(18);
Type created.
SQL> create table TestTable (
   id       number(18) primary key
  ,widgets  TestType
)
Table created.
SQL> delete from testtable
0 rows deleted.
SQL> insert into TestTable values (1, TestType(1,2,3,4))
1 row created.
SQL> insert into TestTable values (2, TestType(5,6,7))
1 row created.
SQL> insert into TestTable values (3, TestType())
1 row created.
SQL> insert into TestTable values (4,null)
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.

SQL> -- show all data with widgets
SQL> select t.id, w.column_value as widget_ids
from testtable t, table(t.widgets) w

        ID WIDGET_IDS
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         1          4
         2          5
         2          6
         2          7

7 rows selected.
SQL> -- show with lag function
SQL> select t.id, lag(w.column_value, 1) over (order by t.id) as widgets_previous
from testtable t, table(t.widgets) w

        ID WIDGETS_PREVIOUS
---------- ----------------
         1                 
         1                1
         1                2
         1                3
         2                4
         2                5
         2                6

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: hi @tbone - what you're returning is not quite what I'm after. You have inserted 4 rows so the select should likewise return 4 rows, row 1 holding row 1's collection and null for the previous collection, row 2 holding row 2's collection and row 1's collection and so on... thanks for the input!

Comment: Ah, ok, I misunderstood what you were looking for.  Joining the table to itself as you suggested seems like the way to go.